# Why are there updates to old Android system images in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, updates

In Android Studio, when I get an update notification it lists the following:

[image]

But I am highly confused as to why on earth there would be an update to older Android system images such as 4.4 KitKat.

Isn't a system image a snapshot in time and immutable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same reason why android devices get updates on fixes for bugs, flaws and security risks.

But you notice sometimes using old platform-tools cause a problem on newer system images, hence when platform-tools get updated, system images likely get updated as well.